# locationManager:didEnterRegion: only called once?

Tags: ios, core-location

I have implemented the Region Monitoring and it works fine. My test app starts monitoring a region when the app launches, and I call `startUpdatingLocation` to update the pin on the map to visualize where I am. Then, using XCode location simulation to jump from Mumbai to San Francisco to London etc.

The map is correctly updated (`didUpdateToLocation` called), and the first time I jump to San Francisco (where I registered the region), I get a correct log. But if I continue jumping around, when I go back to San Francisco, `didEnterRegion` is not called, but I still have this location in my `monitoredRegions` location manager.

**Why is `didEnterRegion` only called once ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the region monitoring methods, you don't need to actively monitor location with -didUpdateToLocation. You need to make sure you have the essentials set up correctly so your app is receiving the callbacks from the OS when you trigger an event.

- Your AppDelegate should have an instance of locationManager up and listening.
- You need to have the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods configured in your AppDelegate (or wherever your locationManagerDelegate is setup)
- Make sure you are creating your regions correctly for monitoring. A CLRegion takes a point (long, lat) and a radius. Add that to be monitored by using the startMonitoringForRegion method.

That is really all there is. I had trouble with these too, and it mainly just comes down to making sure your CLLocationManagerDelegate is configured to handle the callbacks from the OS for the region events. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I have all of this configured like you say... It appears to work but not always. Sometimes a Reminder for the same location will fire but not my app

Comment: Another thing to consider is the maximum radius. There is a size limit imposed on regions... but Apple doesn't say what that size is. There is a max size or maxradius you can call to make sure. Something to consider.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now.